# setting the html of a number of divs of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a no. of divs of a particular class. I assign these divs to an array and want to set the html of each div basing on the index of the array - can anybody help me with the code. The code I was trying is as below:

```
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>

arrayofDays = $('.days');

var FirstDay = 1;
var LastDay = 5;

$(arrayofDays).each(function(i, item) {
        if ((i >= FirstDay) && (i <= LastDay)) {
            $(item[i]).css({'background-color' : '#991'}).html('Weekday');
        }

        else {
            $(item[i]).css({'background-color' : '#fff'}).html('Holiday');
        } 
    });
```

I am trying to set the html of the first and last divs to 'Holiday' and others to 'Weekday'. So far have not been able to make any headway ....

Thanks in advance

Sukalyan

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jQuery selectors

```
var weekend = $('.days:first, .days:last');
var weekday = $('.days').not(weekend);
```

or

```
var FirstDay = 1;
var LastDay = 5;

var weekday = $('.days').slice(FirstDay, LastDay + 1);
var weekend = $('.days').not(weekday);
```

```js
var weekend = $('.days:first, .days:last');
var weekday = $('.days').not(weekend);

weekday.css({'background-color' : '#991'}).html('Weekday');
weekend.css({'background-color' : '#fff'}).html('Holiday');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="days">sunday</div>
<div class="days">monday</div>
<div class="days">tuesday</div>
<div class="days">wednesday</div>
<div class="days">thursday</div>
<div class="days">friday</div>
<div class="days">saturday</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(item)` as selector, second argument in `jQuery.each` is element itself!

```js
var arrayofDays = $('.days');
var FirstDay = 1;
var LastDay = 5;
$(arrayofDays).each(function(i, item) {
  if ((i >= FirstDay) && (i <= LastDay)) {
    $(item).css({
      'background-color': '#991'
    }).html('Weekday');
  } else {
    $(item).css({
      'background-color': '#fff'
    }).html('Holiday');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
```

**Using `index`**

```js
var arrayofDays = $('.days');
var FirstDay = 1;
var LastDay = 5;
$(arrayofDays).each(function(i, item) {
  if ((i >= FirstDay) && (i <= LastDay)) {
    $(arrayofDays[i]).css({
      'background-color': '#991'
    }).html('Weekday');
  } else {
    $(arrayofDays[i]).css({
      'background-color': '#fff'
    }).html('Holiday');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
```